# PDF report not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net

In my project after saving the data into db it will show report (pdf ) in a new page.It working fine on all browsers expect
IE .it will show like below pic [image]

### Code

```
 private string CreateLE_ANEZ()
    {
        try
        {

            ReportDocument oRPT = new ReportDocument();
            oRPT.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Reports/LE-Einzel.rpt"));
            ReportDocument subreportArtikel = new ReportDocument();
            SubreportObject subreportObjectArtikel;
            subreportObjectArtikel = oRPT.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Subreport1"] as SubreportObject;
            subreportArtikel = subreportObjectArtikel.OpenSubreport("LE-Artikel-SubRepoert.rpt");
            CTemplate objTemp = new CTemplate();
            DataTable dtTemplate = objTemp.SelectLETemplate("ANEZ");
            oRPT.SetDataSource(dtTemplate);

            DataTable dtArtikelData = SelectLEArtikel();
            subreportArtikel.SetDataSource(dtArtikelData);
            #region set parameter values
            //AAddressen objCust = new AAddressen();
            //objCust=new CAddressen().SelectAddressen(AddressenID);
            CUsers objUser = new CUsers();
            objUser.UserID = UserID;
            AUsers objAUser = objUser.SelectUserProfile();
            CLand objLand = new CLand();
            objLand.ID = objAUser.Land;
            objLand.SelectLandById();
            objAUser.LandName = objLand.Lnd_Name;
            CUtilities objUtil=new CUtilities();                
            string strDate = LEDate.Day.ToString() + "." + LEDate.Month.ToString() + "." + LEDate.Year.ToString();
            string strLands = SelectLELand();

            /* Requirement No ::  18895       ::: Commented By Jyotheena Jose      :1/30/2014 11:21:17 AM
               string strSender = objAUser.Ort + " : " + strDate + " , " + " " + objAUser.FirmaName +  " " + objAUser.PLZ +" " + objAUser.Street + " , " + objAUser.FirstName + " " + objAUser.LastName;*/
            string strSender = objAUser.Ort + " : " + strDate + " , " + objAUser.FirmaName + ", " + objAUser.Street + ", " + objAUser.PLZ + " " + objAUser.Ort + " , " + objAUser.FirstName + " " + objAUser.LastName + " , " + objAUser.Position;
            string strLEDate = LEDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-";
            string strCum = "";
            string strNoCum = "";
            if (IsCumulation == "T")
                strCum = "X";
            else
                strNoCum ="X";

            switch (LENumber.Trim().Length)
            {
                case 1: strLEDate += "00" + LENumber;
                    break;
                case 2: strLEDate += "0" + LENumber;
                    break;
                default: strLEDate += LENumber;
                    break;
            }
            ParameterDiscreteValue pDescValue;
            ParameterFieldDefinitions pFielddDefs;
            ParameterFieldDefinition pFieldLoc = null;
            ParameterValues pValues = new ParameterValues();
            pFielddDefs = oRPT.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            pDescValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pLandList", strLands);
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pSender", strSender);
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pLEDate", strLEDate);
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pBemerkungen", Bemerk);
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pCum", strCum);
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pNoCum", strNoCum);
            CreateParameterFields(pDescValue, pFielddDefs, pFieldLoc, pValues, "pCumtext", Cumulation);
            #endregion

            string strFileName = "Pdf/" + UserID.ToString().Trim() + "Einzel.pdf";   

            if (!Directory.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Pdf")))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Pdf"));
            if (File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strFileName)))
                File.Delete(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strFileName));
            oRPT.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(strFileName));
            return strFileName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("CLE->CreateLE_ANEZ", ex);
        }
    }
```

After IN New page (ViewPdf1.aspx)

```
rotected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["rpt"] == null)
                return;
            else
            {
                string strValues = Session["rpt"].ToString();
                string[] strData = strValues.Split(',');
                //Session.Remove("rpt");
                //ViewState["rpt"] = strData[1].Trim();
                //ViewState["LENo"] = strData[0].Trim();
                //string strUrl = ViewState["rpt"].ToString();
                string strUrl = strData[1].Trim();
                dvPdfLoader.InnerHtml = "<object data='" + strUrl + "' type='application/pdf'  width='100%' height='468px'></object>";
                string strQuery = Request.QueryString["s"];
                if (strQuery != null && CUtilities.Decrypt(strQuery.Trim()) == "mailsent")
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "E-Mail erfolgreich gesendet";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please help to solve this error..

Regards
Jithesh

Comment: What is the IE version?

Comment: My suggestion would be to update Adobe Reader if it is not already up to date.

Comment: The version is (IE 11..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE IS THE SOLUTION :)

Internet Explorer 10 & 11 are considered as the best possible versions of Microsoft‘s proprietary browser; Internet Explorer. With Windows 8 as well as Windows 7, you can use IE 10 and IE 11. Well in both these iterations, some users have reported facing a problem that, whenever they try to download and open PDF file, Internet Explorer will not open PDF files.

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/pdf-files-will-open-internet-explorer